# php datetime and zone

Tags: php, datetime, cakephp

I'm trying to convert a string of time to datetime with meridian but I got wrong datetime.
Here is my code:

```
$timeZone = 'Europe/Warsaw';
date_default_timezone_set($timeZone);
$millis  = 1540399680000;
$seconds = $millis / 1000;
$date    = date("d/m/Y H:i:s a", $seconds);
debug($date);
$timeZone = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Warsaw');
$formato  = "d/m/Y H:i:s a";
$fecha    = DateTime::createFromFormat($formato, $date, $timeZone);
debug($fecha);
debug($fecha->format('Y'));
debug($fecha->format('a'));
```

result for debug($date)

```
24/10/2018 18:48:00 pm
```

result for debug($fecha)

```
object(DateTime) {
    date => '2018-10-25 06:48:00.000000'
    timezone_type => (int) 3
    timezone => 'Europe/Warsaw'
}
```

what i am expecting is at debug($fecha);
    `date => '2018-10-24 06:48:00.000000'`

Comment: What do you expect to get?

Comment: `$fecha` it's a datetime object, you may format it as your needs.

Comment: `debug($fecha->format('d/m/Y H:i:s a'));` it will give your desired solutions

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use [CakeTime::format()](https://api.cakephp.org/2.9/class-CakeTime.html#_format)? F.ex.:

```
$date = CakeTime::format($seconds, 'd/m/Y H:i:s a', false, 'Europe/Warsaw');
debug($date);
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on the documentation ( http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php ), the DateTime createFormFormat function returns a DateTime Object. If you want to get a direct output, follow this code.

```
$timeZone = 'Europe/Warsaw';
date_default_timezone_set($timeZone);
$millis  = 1540399680000;
$seconds = $millis / 1000;
$date    = date("d/m/Y H:i:s a", $seconds);
debug($date);
$timeZone = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Warsaw');
$formato  = "d/m/Y H:i:s a";
// instead of this
//$fecha    = DateTime::createFromFormat($formato, $date, $timeZone);
// add ->format in the end
$fecha    = DateTime::createFromFormat($formato, $date, $timeZone)->format($formato);
debug($fecha);
```